# What's a good way to put authors into groups

Tags: author

I have 7 companies contributing to one blog, and each company has 3 authors. I'd like to show all posts by all authors of one company. Is that possible?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly - you have 21 people posting.  You would like to make 7 groups of authors, and have 7 archive pages each showing posts from the specific company?

Answer (score 4):

To do this literally (put authors into groups) best way would probably be to create custom taxonomy for users. See [custom user taxonomies in WordPress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) for reference.

However the end result you are looking for does not really deal with grouping users - it deals with grouping posts.

Registering custom taxonomy ("company") for posts would be more simple and straightforward.

See [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple thing to do would be to add a meta-box to the "users" screen.  Call it "company", and use a drop-down or check box and associate users with a company when they are created.

If you didn't want to hard code this yourself - you could look into this plugin (or similar).

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Then in your theme, you set up your query using the new meta-box to filter down by company.